# is it ok to store salt and encypted SSN using AES 256 in same table

Tags: encryption, aes, pii

I am using AES256 algorithm to encrypt SSN ( because I want to decrypt that and show it to user on UI ).

Will it be ok to store SSN specific salt and encrypted password in same table ?

Comment: If you "encrypt" with SHA256 you will be very disappointed when it's time to decrypt it. That's when you'll discover that SHA256 is a hashing algorithm.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk : sorry I meant to say AES256 instead of SHA256